# CGRect intersects 4 rects. How to figure out which rect it intersects mostly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

If you need more details: I have UICollectionViewCell which is draggable. When the cell overlaps other cells during dragging I want to know which one it overlaps mostly in order to replace overlapped cell with this cell. Is there any **efficient** way to do this? I found nothing helpful in CGGeometry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CGRectUnion() in a loop, the one with a smallest area will be the one with the greatest overlap.  You could write a function that deals with (and returns a) CGRects, but youd probably need to loop though your views (cells) again to find the correct one, so I'd keep it UIView level...
Eg

```
    //helpers

    CGFloat CGRectGetArea(CGRect theRect){
    return theRect.size.width * theRect.size.height;
    }

 -(UIView *)viewClosestToView:(UIView*)keyView fromViews:(NSArray*)comparisonViews{

  UIView *result=nil;
  CGFloat smallestArea=0.0;

   for (UIView *view in comparisonViews){

    CGFloat area = CGRectGetArea( CGRectUnion(view.frame, keyView.frame)  );

    if ((area < smallestArea)|| ((NSInteger)smallestArea==0) ){
    smallestArea=area;
    result=view;
    }

  }
return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jef! This is another relevant approach! But how to compare areas then?

Comment: can you see the code i wrote there?  pass the cell that is dragged in as keyView and the others in an array into that method there, the little helper function does the area.  If you like Gerd's approach better (its the same approach, just inverted) you could alter it slightly to do that.  I was typing code when he answered, didn't see it at the time

Comment: I see this, but the problem is in hardcoded value of 600.0. I don't need to compare it against some value. Instead, I want to get the smallest(in your approach) area from all. How to do this?

Comment: 600.0 is just an arbitrary value i dropped in to start with, because our comparison is < (less than) we can hardly start with a CGFloat's default value (0.0).  Ill edit it hang on

Comment: It looks like I need a function similar to: fmin(float,float,float,float)

Comment: well i think this is better, because it may sometimes overlap with two cells or three cells.... (ie not always 4)

Comment: Yes, you are right! This works! What is more it works not only with 4 overlapped rects.

Answer (score 1):

Use CGRectIntersection(r1,r2) to find the intersection rect (if any). Multiply width and height of the returned rectangle to get the area. Compare the 4 areas to find the largest.

This should be way more than fast enough for UI manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I already guessed the answer. But thank you for clarifying that it is quite efficient approach! Accept your answer in 4 mins

Comment: But how to compare this areas then? Store them in array? Compare float values against each other? Is there any better way of doing this?